# Create a function to generate data frame using variables

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to generate a data frame as follow where the number of 1s and 2s and 3s in column A can be determined by three different variables and the values in column B increase one by one.

```
A   B
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   4
2   5
3   6
3   7
3   8
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating a DataFrame from the following dictionary, where `a,b,c` are the number of `1,2,3`s respectively.

```
a,b,c = 3,2,3

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1]*a + [2]*b + [3]*c,
                   'B': [n+1 for n in range(a+b+c)]})
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  2  4
4  2  5
5  3  6
6  3  7
7  3  8
```